# Опыт более 10 лет! Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире в предложениях:

1. Опыт работы в данной сфере (-) более 10 лет.
2. Требование: опыт работы в данной сфере (-) от 10 лет.

Answer (score 2):

А я бы поставила тире в этих предложениях, рассмотрев их как неполные.

Опыт работы в данной сфере (составляет)более 10 лет.
Требование: опыт работы в данной сфере (необходим) от 10 лет.

Answer (score 1):

Правила не требуют.Опыт каков?-более 10 лет.Это не сущ. в именит. пад.

Но тире возможно для усиления значения длительности периода,интонационное, авторское.В деловом стиле тоже возможно для подчёркивания категоричности требования.

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Если вспомнить общую теорию вопроса, то она такова.

Тире ставится, если необходимо отделить состав подлежащего от состава именного сказуемого, при этом подлежащее и сказуемое обычно выражены существительным в начальной форме, неопределенной формой глагола или ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫМ (в этих случаях грамматическая роль названных слов не всегда определяется однозначно):Трижды три – девять. Пять и два – семь.Длина Волги – 3688 километров. Средняя скорость ветра – пять метров в секунду.

Однако в специальной литературе тире не ставится:Максимальная дальность действия прибора два километра. Стоимость товара пять тысяч рублей. Температура плавления золота 1063 градуса.

В приведенных примерах тире лучше поставить для обозначения границ подлежащего и сказуемого. Для сравнения: Опыт работы более 10 лет приветствуется (нет тире, здесь оборот в роли несогласованного определения).

Но есть еще неплохой вариант: Опыт работы в данной сфере не менее 10 лет. Здесь тире не ставится перед частицей НЕ, которая и обозначает границу между главными членами.